# How can I get the data from the CSV file and declare a variable for each column using python?

Tags: python-2.7, csv

I have a csv file that might look like this (contents variable-format not):

"Red","House","1/1/2010","Green Eggs and Ham",1,10

The csv file that will always have just one row of data and 6 columns

How can I get the data from the cvs file and declare a variable for each column value using python?

ie.

var1 = Column1

Var2 = Column2

var3 = Column3

etc.

so that when I type "print var3", the following value would appear.

"1/1/2010"

I thought the following would work but I got an error message saying NameError: name var3 is not defined.

```
f = csv.reader(open("C:\Test\Test.csv", "rb"))

for row in f:
    var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6 = row

print var3
```

I need to use these values later on the script. Ideas anyone. Super new to this. Python 2.7

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Answer (score 0):

Each row is treated as a list in Python. So, if 'line' contains your 6 elements, 'line[0]' is your first column element.

Also, I changed the 'rt' to 'r' as I was getting some other sort of error, but try this:

```
import csv
with open('C:\\test.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
f = csv.reader(csvfile)
for line in f:
    print (line[2])
```

Comment: Sorry this was written in Python 3, the print statement parenthesis will need to be ignored.